# Why is my static html file not found in an Azure web app?

Tags: html, azure

I created a web app from the Azure portal. I didn't see an option for a static html website, so I chose Node.js when asked to choose a type. Then I set up continuous deployment with my github repo that contained my html file and synced. I see the html file in the Azure command prompt directory listing, but when I [browse to the location I get a 404](http://moveyourfilters.azurewebsites.net/switch.html).

Why can't I browse to that location? I'm guessing there is some property hiding files with the .html extenstion or some such thing. I don't know where to look.

[image: Azure 404]
[image: Directory listing]

Comment: Whats the contents of the parent directory?

Comment: Guessing you need an NPM module to serve static files.

Comment: 4 subdirectories. Is that relevant? I didn't create them myself. They were created either by the azure portal's app creation process or the continuous deployment of the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuous deployment option in Azure creates and maintains a web.config file specific to node.js. That was preventing access to the html file. Deleting the web.config isn't enough in this case because continuous deployment redeploys the file. There is a checkbox in the release manager for web.config that must be unchecked.